# Calculate average if cell is not blank

Tags: excel

I'm building a scoring spreadsheet that is gradually populated as additional data is received.

I want to create a formula that will give me the running average (that will change as more data is inputted) that is dependent on 2 columns.

Essentially I have 3 columns: Column A has a Report #, Column B the name of an organization, and Column C which has a score.

The formula should calculate an average that does not include blank or zero scores in the calculation but only uses those scores associated with a specific organization.

I've tried the following:

```
=IF(B2:B100="organization", AVERAGEIF(C2:C100, ">0"))
```

Also:

```
=IF(B2:B100="organization", IF(C2:C100="","",AVERAGE(C2:C100)
```

In both instances I get a `#Value` error.

The issue is that the `AVERAGE()` or `AVERAGEIF()` function need to target only those scores that meet the B2:B100="organization" criteria

Comment: IsBlank / IsEmpty() ?

Comment: ISBLANK() won't work as there is a formula in Column C

Comment: =AVERAGEIFS(C2:C100,C2:C100,">0",C2:C100,"<>""")

Comment: But you need multiple criteria so you need AVERAGEIFS not AVERAGEIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AVERAGEIFS`

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C100, B2:B100, "organization", C2:C100, ">0")
```

According to the [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) this takes the range you wish to average followed by `n` range/criteria pairs.

This formula finds the average of Column C between rows 2 and 100, where the B column value is "organization" and C column value is greater than zero.  This will also automatically handle blanks in the range.